# sql recursion calls

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the scenario where The session is cancelled I need to come up with the list of contiguous (sessions within 30 minutes for the same instructor) and adjoin session (different instructor, same car within 30 minutes).

I partially got the list build however, if there adjoin session all I need to check if it has contiguous sessions and do not check for another adjoin session.

The sample data is below. I get 3 records in return. the record 1 get cancelled.So i look for contiguous sessions there are none. Then look for adjoin session which is record 2. For record 2 look for contigious session there are none. The adjoin session should not appear.

```
sessionKey  LKey  instructorKey sessionStart              sessionEnd                carKey    FirstKey
1            13   36754         2015-07-01 10:30:00.000   2015-07-01 12:30:00.000   139       1
2            34   12383         2015-07-01 08:15:00.000   2015-07-01 10:15:00.000   139       1
3            34   8             2015-07-01 06:00:00.000   2015-07-01 08:00:00.000   139       1
```

The code is provided below:

```
DECLARE @CancelTime   datetime
SET @CancelTime = '2015-07-01 10:30:00'


            DECLARE @DataFromYourTables TABLE (
                sessionKey      int         NOT NULL,
                locationKey     smallint,
                sessionStart    datetime    NOT NULL,
                sessionEnd      datetime    NOT NULL,
                instructorKey   int         NOT NULL,
                Flag            int,
                carKey          smallint    NOT NULL,
                cnt             int,
                bookingLock     int,
                hubLock         int  
            )

            INSERT INTO @DataFromYourTables

            SELECT  s.sessionKey,
                    s.locationKey,
                    su.sessionStart,
                    su.sessionEnd,
                    su.instructorKey,
                    su.btwSeatsOverride AS Flag,
                    s.carKey,
                    (SELECT count(sm.sessionKey) from sessionMap SM
                        where SM.sessionKey = s.sessionKey
                    )cnt,
                    isNUll(S.bookingLock,0) as bookingLock,
                    isNUll(S.hubLock,0) as hubLock
            FROM    session s
            JOIN    sessionunit su ON su.sessionKey = s.sessionKey
            JOIN    product     p  ON p.productKey = s.productKey AND p.productTypeKey IN (2,4)
            WHERE   CONVERT(date, su.sessionStart) = CONVERT(date, @CancelTime)
            AND    (su.instructorKey = 1 OR s.carKey = 1)


            DECLARE @Results TABLE (
                sessionKey      int,
                locationKey     smallint,
                instructorKey   int,
                sessionStart    datetime,
                sessionEnd      datetime,
                carKey          smallint,
                Flag            int,
                FirstKey        int,
                cnt             int,
                bookingLOck     int,
                hubLock         int 
           )

           ;WITH myCTE AS
                (
                SELECT  sessionKey,
                        locationKey,
                        instructorKey,
                        sessionStart,
                        sessionEnd,
                        carKey,
                        Flag,
                        sessionKey AS FirstKey,
                        cnt,
                        bookingLock,
                        hubLock
                FROM    @DataFromYourTables
                WHERE   sessionStart = @CancelTime


                UNION ALL
                SELECT  a.sessionKey,
                        a.locationKey,
                        a.instructorKey,
                        a.sessionStart,
                        a.sessionEnd,
                        a.carKey,
                        a.Flag,
                        FirstKey,
                        a.cnt,
                        a.bookingLock,
                        a.hubLock
                FROM    @DataFromYourTables a
                JOIN    myCTE b
                ON      b.sessionEnd BETWEEN DATEADD(n, -29, a.SessionStart) AND DATEADD(n, 29, a.SessionStart) and b.instructorKey = a.instructorKey 
                )
                INSERT INTO @Results
                SELECT * FROM myCTE



                ;WITH myCTE AS
                (
                SELECT  sessionKey,
                        locationKey,
                        instructorKey,
                        sessionStart,
                        sessionEnd,
                        carKey,
                        Flag,
                        sessionKey AS FirstKey,
                        cnt,
                        bookingLock,
                        hubLock
                FROM     @DataFromYourTables
                WHERE   sessionStart = @CancelTime
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  a.sessionKey,
                        a.locationKey,
                        a.instructorKey,
                        a.sessionStart,
                        a.sessionEnd,
                        a.carKey,
                        a.Flag,
                        FirstKey,
                        a.cnt,
                        a.bookingLock,
                        a.hubLock
                FROM    @DataFromYourTables a
                JOIN    myCTE b
                ON      b.sessionStart BETWEEN DATEADD(n, -29, a.SessionEnd) AND DATEADD(n, 29, a.SessionEnd) 
                and b.instructorKey <> a.instructorKey 
                and b.carKey = a.carKey

                )

                INSERT INTO @Results
                SELECT * FROM myCTE
               WHERE  sessionKey <> FirstKey




                SELECT  *,
                        CASE
                            WHEN sessionKey <> FirstKey THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                        END Comment
                FROM    @Results
                ORDER BY sessionStart
```

Desired results:

```
SessionKey  LKey  instructorKey  sessionStart             sessionEnd               carKey  FirstKey
1           13    36754          2015-07-01 10:30:00.000  2015-07-01 12:30:00.000  139     1 
2           34    12383          2015-07-01 08:15:00.000  2015-07-01 10:15:00.000  139     1
```

Comment: It's hard to ascertain what you need. Could you provide your desired results from your sample data and make sure that your sample data illustrates every possible case that can occur in your actual table.

Comment: the desired result issessionKey  LKey  instructorKey sessionStart              sessionEnd                carKey    FirstKey
1            13   36754         2015-07-01 10:30:00.000   2015-07-01 12:30:00.000   139       1
2            34   12383         2015-07-01 08:15:00.000   2015-07-01 10:15:00.000   139       1